# Azure Data Factory - download Json Defitions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

So I am facing the following problem: I have a bunch of Azure Data Factory V1
Pipelines in one specific data factory, these pipelines, each have, around 400 data sets.
I need to move all of them to a new resource group / environment and put their json definition in a git repo.

So my questions is, how can I download all the pipelines definitions for a data factory and all the data sets definitions in their json format from Azure?

I don't want to click each one and copy-paste from the Azure UI, as it will take ages.

Answer (score 1):

Call Rest API is good way for both V1 and V2. See [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/v2).

Answer (score 0):

For ADF V1, you can try using Visual Studio.

1. Connect via Cloud Explorer to your data factory.
2. Select the data factory and choose Export to New Data Factory Project

This is documented on [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Azure+Data+Factory/139478/).

Another thing to try is to have Azure script out an ARM template of the Data Factory.